# What is the origin of the phrase a "hung jury"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, phrase-origin

As the title suggests, I'm curious about the origin of a "hung jury" when the jury doesn't come to a decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This column by Adam Freedman](http://thepartyofthefirstpart.blogspot.com/2004/04/column-jury-is-out.html) discusses the phrase:

> The Oxford English Dictionary lists the first printed reference to a hung jury in Edwin Bryant’s What I Saw in California (1848-49) in which he states: “The jury . . . were what is called ‘hung’; they could not agree . . .”
>   Bryant’s phrasing obviously suggests that the phrase was already in common use by the late 1840’s. ... The earliest use of the term in a law report appears in an 1821 case, Evans v. McKinsey. ... it appears that the term developed somewhere in the south during the early 19th Century.
>   Linguistically, the phrase seems to derive from the sense of “hung” to mean caught, suspended or delayed (“I got hung up at the office”).

[The Hung Jury: The American Jury's Insights and Contemporary Understanding](http://www.ncsconline.org/D_Research/cjs/pdf/Crim_L_Bull.pdf) [PDF] references the same cases, with a few more details (see footnote, pg 1).

Comment: I think you're on the right track, and "hung" along the lines of "suspended" is probably where to look.

Answer (score 5):

The following [clip](http://books.google.com/books?id=_l8AAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA480-IA2&dq=%22hung%20jury%22&hl=en&ei=ChcJTvn6CKi20AHh6v12&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22hung%20jury%22&f=false) from an 1838 issue of the *Southern Literary Messenger* confirms both the geography and time frame mentioned in @aedia's answer:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=_l8AAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA480-IA2&dq=%22hung+jury%22&hl=en&ei=ChcJTvn6CKi20AHh6v12&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22hung%20jury%22&f=false]

Answer (score 5):

The *OED*'s earliest citation is 1848, but I found an earlier example with the same meaning in *Niles' Weekly Register* of [November 23, 1822](http://books.google.fi/books?id=xT8WV8HVf3IC&pg=PA192&dq=%22hung%20*%20jury%22%20OR%20%22jury%20*%20hung%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=d5j1ULvfC6Wg4gTmz4DABA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22jury%20was%20hung%22%20&f=false):

[image: Lithgow, at Richmond, famous about a certain check, was lately again on his trial--but the jury was "hung;" that is, divided on the verdict, and no other indictment was to be tried "during the present term of the court."]

Another meaning of *hung* is *suspended*, and the jury is figuratively suspended as it cannot make a decision.

Comment: I've sent this antedating to the [OED](http://www.oup.com/uk/oedsubform/).

Answer (score 4):

A year earlier than Hugo's November 23, 1822, instance from *Niles' Weekly Register* is this [very brief untitled item](http://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=GL18210828.2.13&txq=hung+jury) from the *[Leesburg, Virginia] Genius of Liberty* (August 28, 1821):

> In Virginia, and in sundry other places nearer home, a jury that cannot agree, is called a *hung jury*. ...thus, when the *jury* are hung, the *criminal* is not!—[Fredonian.

The *Fredonian* cited as the source of this item is probably the New Brunswick, New Jersey *Fredonian*, a contemporaneous newspaper.

This instance establishes not only that, by August 1821, the term *hung jury* was in use in Virginia (and elsewhere) in the sense of "jury unable to reach a unanimous decision,"  but also that people were already making jokes that played on the double-entendre meaning of *hung*.

Comment: Good find - you should submit it to the OED, too.